# Apache is running but phpmyadmin shows blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

After installing xampp in my computer yesterday, it worked normally along the day. Today, I am about to continue my project. Apache and MySQL are running but localhost/phpmyadmin in my browser is showing blank page without any error message, just totally white screen. Then I am trying to open my application, localhost/stationaryshop, it is working properly including CRUDE process without any problem. Even if xampp control panel is run as administrator, it also couldn't work. How could I fix this?
I use xampp v3.2.2, and windows 7.

Comment: First step always to perform is: _take a look into your http servers error log file_. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: I found this : server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name. I've searched some solution about that. But those solution just recommend to change the port. I haven't tried yet because my 80 port is just used by apache.

Comment: A server certificate issue has nothing to do with the port the server binds to, but with the certificate. That would mean you configured a ssl certificate (for https usage) which is not valid for a given request. Is that an old entry or does it occur with every new request?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by old entry or every new request?

Comment: All entries in the error log file have a timestamp. You should be able to tell if that entry you mentioned is old or new. With "every new request" I ask if such an entry gets added for every request to your phpmyadmin application or not.

Comment: It's happen all the time.

Comment: Ok, so you will have to take a look what certificate that is and why it causes such issue. Most likely you are using different host names to access your server? Like some internal domain name _and_ `localhost` or an IP address? Note that the host name has to be included in such a certificate, otherwise the certificate cannot be used for the request. Why did you configure a certificate at all? Do you _really_ want to use https (ssl encryption) or whas that by accident? If you configured that by purpose, then what host names did you specify in the certificate?

Comment: Or maybe you enabled https _without_ installing a usable certificate and now `phpmyadmin` internally is using an encrypted connection whilst you access everything else without encryption? Did you configure some https URL somewhere? Maybe as a base address in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: No, i don't have different host name and I didn't change any setting on this computer or xampp. It worked normally yesterday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129800/discussion-between-arkascha-and-diyah).

Answer (score 11):

I was able to resolve the issue by clearing my browsing data -> Cached images and files.

I am using Google Chrome: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

**Steps:**

1. Click the top-right menu button -> "More tools" -> "Clear browsing data...".
2. Check "Cached images and files" checkbox.
3. Click the "Clear browsing data" button.

Answer (score 9):

None of these answers worked for me.

First I was able to debug the issue by running:

`php index.php`

On the command-line in the phpmyadmin folder.

It said there was a memory size exhausted but it was only trying to allocate 4Mb when my php memory limit was actually 1Gb.

However when I looked in the php.ini file I had set the `memory_limit` to:

`1GB` instead of the correct syntax of `1G`.

Remember the correct syntax is G for Gigabytes and M for Megabytes. Once that was corrected phpmyadmin was finally loading properly.

Comment: This really saved the day. Thanks for your keen observation.

Answer (score 2):

I just open the Developer Option on Chrome and disabled the cache, refresh the page and it works perfectly fine even after I close the Developer Option again.

Answer (score 2):

This happend to me when I changed my memory_limit to 4096MB (32Bit limitation).

Answer (score 1):

Today I had this same problem and resolved by increasing the value of the **max_execution_time** property in the **php.ini** file and temporarily **disabling the cache of my browser**.

I believe that, for most cases, it is only necessary to reload phpMyAdmin with the browser cache disabled.

---

In my case, I verified in my apache error.log file this line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\xampp\\phpMyAdmin\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php on line 354
```

Then, I edit this property in my 'php.ini':

```
max_execution_time=300
```

After that, in Chrome Browser, I opened the 'Developer Tools' (Ctrl+Shift+I), I clicked on 'Network Tab' and, finnaly, I selected 'Disable Cache' checkbox. I reloaded the phpMyAdmin page with this Developer Tool opened and success!

In the next phpMyAdmin runs, you do **not** need to keep the 'developer tool' open.

Answer (score 1):

This happened on my clean CentOS7 + httpd + php7 installation. When I tried to run `php phpmyadmin/index.php` in the console I did see the generated html, but the web page was blank. After hours of print debugging thanks to phpmyadmin trying to be clever and overriding error display settings to make errors silent, I narrowed it down to it not being able to initiate a session.

A quick test is to create a php file: `<?php session_start(); ?>` and see if it throws any errors in the browser. In my case it said that it couldn't save the session file in `/var/lib/php/session/...`.

The solution was to edit `/etc/php.ini` and enable `session.save_path = "/tmp"`. This was not enough since `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` was overwriting this value, so I also commented out `php_value session.save_path "/var/lib/php/session"` under `<IfModule mod_php7.c>` there. After restarting httpd the phpmyadmin started loading.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when I was using Internet Explorer as I was running Apache on a Windows 7 virtual machine and that was the default browser.

I downloaded Google Chrome and it worked: I stopped seeing that blank page and could access the phpMyAdmin panel.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me;
Go to php.ini file, find `open_basedir`, then comment it by introducing ';'(semi-colon) as depicted below

```
;open_basedir = "C:\xampp\htdocs"
```

You might as well turn error display on to see warnings on your browser(still in php.ini)

```
display_errors = Off
```

to

```
display_errors = On
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the webserver in *Program Files (x86)* folder and one setting in the php.ini was without quotes. I added it and after a restart, phpmyadmin worked. So, change

```
include_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR
```

to

```
include_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

rebooting my device solved the issue for me