# PhpMyAdmin only displays blank page- Oracle Linux 8

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a fresh VM of Oracle Linux 8 (5.4.17-2136.307.3.4.el8uek.x86_64). I have installed HTTPd, MariaDB and PHP 7.2.34. I followed the steps on installing phpmyadmin listed here (https://techviewleo.com/install-phpmyadmin-on-oracle-linux/). Problem is, when I go to 192.168.X.X/phpmyadmin it's just a blank page. If I put an info.php in my /usr/share/phpmyadmin folder, it displays that properly. So I assume my directory permissions, PHP, ans SELinux are all configured/working correctly. I can't seem to find any errors in any logs or anything to direct me to the problem. I'm at my wits end here. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache is running but phpmyadmin shows blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971796/apache-is-running-but-phpmyadmin-shows-blank-page)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not answer my question. I have not modified any memory or execution time parameters. This is a new install. There are no errors listed in the httpd error log either.

Comment: I guess I'll answer my own question. I hired a developer to look at it, and he noticed that it needed the php-json extension. He installed that, and it works now.